# Fade image at the top

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have a vertical image that looks like this:

[image]

What I need is for the image to fade at the top only so that it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Here's the JSFiddle I've started: [**http://jsfiddle.net/R6KSM/**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6KSM/)

The CSS I have set up is simply:

```
.line {
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/UEfCV17.png') repeat-y;
}

.line > .content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: It looks like you've already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687599/fading-vertical-line

Comment: Considering this question is better than that one and there are no accepted answers for it, I'm voting to close the question @Skelly linked as a dupe of this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `<div>` with a white-to-transparent gradient:

HTML

```
<div class="line">
    <div class="fadeTop"></div>
    <div class="content">
        This is just a sample paragraph.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fadeTop{
    height:20px;width:100%;position:absolute;left:0; top:0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
```

(I used [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for this particular situation)

Check it out: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6KSM/3/)